# Bootstrap NavBar does not show in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, twitter-bootstrap

My site using bootstrap 2.1.1 and found a lot of 'problem' when showing in IE8. One of the problem is Navigation Bar, i simplify and replicate "the bug" here:

http://doxadigital.com/scrape/menutest.html

all .css and .js is by default, the code to display navbar is also taken from bootstrap documentation (in order to reduce typo/syntax error)

As you see, the content of menu is not shown in IE8 while it shown in other browser.

Any solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is some hack in bootstrap.min.css

in class ".collapse" remove overflow hidden then you will get you output :-)

Comment: i remove inline style 'height="0px"' , and the link displayed and found another problem... the dropdown menu is hidden... oh boy this getting frustating...

Comment: remove overflow:hidden not height. and and menu is not creating any issue in that case i tested on my system

Comment: its inline and its in css as well so remove height:"0px" and overflow:hidden as well

Comment: Hi.. thanks ! btw, i tried to compare between bootstrap documentation on http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/ and mine... and i found my IE display it differently (with bugs).  But then i upload the docs to my server, and try to open with IE and it runs just as original bootstrap documentation. So there's problem with the script that run locally.. any idea to solve this ?

Comment: @Viktor : it's because IE8 use compatibility mode (render as IE7) by default on local sites.

Answer (score 9):

i have removed overflow hidden and dosen't work. but with making this

```
.navbar-inner{ filter:none;}
```

instead of in bootstrap.css

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffffff', endColorstr='#fff2f2f2', GradientType=0);
```

I can see my navbar in IE 8 & 9

Hope that helps